# How to get into a PoA (private) chain?

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, proof-of-authority

I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Demo-PoA-tutorial) to set up a private chain with PoA some days ago.
And I run a PoA chain successfully.
But today I restart my server.
And I can't start (or get into?) the PoA chain which I set up with command
`parity --config node0.toml`. I think it because I restart my server and the authority has changed...

The error information is:

```
Loading config file from node0.toml
2017-06-26 16:29:00  Starting Parity/v1.6.8-beta-c396229-20170608/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.17.0
2017-06-26 16:29:00  State DB configuration: fast
2017-06-26 16:29:00  Operating mode: active
Consensus signer account not found for the current chain. You can create an account via RPC, UI or `parity account new --chain HyperAlbum-chain.json --keys-path /tmp/parity/node0/keys`.
```

And my node0.toml is:

```
[parity]
chain = "HyperAlbum-chain.json"
base_path = "/tmp/parity/node0"
[network]
port = 30300
[rpc]
port = 8540
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
interface = "10.4.20.69"
[ui]
port = 8180
[dapps]
port = 8080
[account]
password = ["node.pwds"]
[mining]
engine_signer = "0x00525DBE671740a5F943Cd49a3e7f7D46075B07e"
reseal_on_txs = "none"
```

So how to get into a PoA chain again if I restart it? Or maybe I can't restart the parity?

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: What does parity say when you run it? Did you place a relative path for the chain spec or absolute path? (in the config)

Comment: Emmmmmm... Because I have redeployed my PoA chain so I can't tell waht did parity say. I will restart my server and tell it later. I Thanks your advice :) And I set the base_path in the node.toml that "/tmp/parity/node0", I don't know whether it is the "chain spec"?

Comment: I have edited my question and add the error now .Thanks~ :)

Comment: Oh no... I think I know why. Because I set the base_bash under /tmp. If I restart my server it well be delete... That's so embarrassed... Thanks!

Comment: Please, don't delete questions, rather answer them yourself to help users in future with similar issues - thanks!

Comment: any update as i change the path but still i am getting same issue.

Comment: so what did you do exactly to fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:) Hah. With the advice of @5chdn, I checked my *.toml. And I found that I set my base_path to /tmp,(and the tutorial set the same, too. So I think if you want to reconnect with your chain, don't set base_path like that.) in the Ubuntu the files under this folder will be deleted when power off...
Thanks a lot~ :)